# jpackage command is not recognized

Tags: java, jpackage

I am trying to package a jar file into an executable file using the jpackage tool in Java, but the command is not recognized in the command prompt using Windows 10 and Java version:

```
> java --version
java 17.0.1 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have the full JDK installed and the command javac is recognized.

I checked my computer with the "where java javac jpackage" command and it only found the first two in the CommonFiles folder.

I looked in the folder path "ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-17.0.1\jmods" and both the "jdk.jlink.jmod" and "jdk.jpackage.jmod" files are present.

Can someone please help me figure out why the tool isn't recognized by Windows?

Comment: Is `javac` recognized?

Comment: Are you sure you have the JDK and not just the JRE?

Comment: You need a full JDK

Comment: Hmm ... this is strange, given that Oracle stopped shipping "JRE" distros after Java 8.   I wonder if the OP has set up the PATH in an unusual way?

Comment: Did you already or previously have older (<=8) Oracle/Sun Java installed on this system? Try `where java javac jpackage` (if in powershell use `where.exe` to avoid the where-object alias) and see if the first two are actually in either `\Program Files [(x86)]\Common Files` or `\ProgramData` somewhere. In CMD do `path` and look for all Oracle-related entries; in powershell use `$env:path -split ';'` which is much easier to look at.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue to be the way my Environment Variables were set up for Java.  To fix my problem, I went into the `JAVA_HOME` variable and changed the entry from

`C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-17.0.1\lib`

to

`C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-17.0.1`

Next I updated the `path` variable to include `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin"`.  Before I had it listed as `C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin`.  Both of these changes were made under the System variables using the "Edit" button.   I want to thank dave_thompson_085 for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm not convinced by this.  Certainly the old version of `JAVA_HOME` was incorrect.  But the command shell doesn't use `JAVA_HOME` to find things ... normally.  If `PATH` previously had included "C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin", then the command shell should have found the `jpackage` in "C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin"

Comment: This worked for me. I think the trick was adding $JAVA_HOME\bin to PATH so jpackage could be found.